# Convert Keypoints to cv::Mat in OpenCV with C++ for TriangulatePoints

Tags: c++, opencv

I am new in the field of CV and trying to Triangulate Points between three Pictures but for the beginning, I want to Triangulate between two Pictures.
For that, I made these Steps:

1. Feature detection with AKAZE
2. Feature matching by NORM_HAMMING
3. Filter the Matches
4. Match the filtered descriptors with the KeyPoint Coordinates

After that, I have a Vector of KeyPoints for each Image of the same size.
Know i want to convert this Vector to "cv::Mat", so that i can use the TriangulatPoints function:

```
std::vector<cv::KeyPoint>::iterator it_1;
std::vector<cv::Point2f> points_1;

for(it_1 = keypoints_matched_1.begin() ; it_1!=keypoints_matched_1.end() ; it_1++)
{
    points_1.push_back(it_1->pt);
}
cv::Mat pointmatrix1(points_1);



std::vector<cv::KeyPoint>::iterator it_2;
std::vector<cv::Point2f> points_2;

for(it_2 = keypoints_matched_2.begin() ; it_2!=keypoints_matched_2.end() ; it_2++)
{
    points_2.push_back(it_2->pt);
}
cv::Mat pointmatrix2(points_2);

std::vector<cv::Mat> points3D;
std::vector<cv::Mat> points_all={pointmatrix1, pointmatrix2};
cv::sfm::triangulatePoints(points_all,Proj_matrices,points3D);
```

I keep running into this Error:

error: (-215:Assertion failed) points2d_tmp[i].rows == 2 && points2d_tmp[i].cols == n_points in function 'triangulatePoints'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pointmatrix1` `pointmatrix2` should be 2xN matrices containing floats.
Right now they're 1xN matrices containing `cv::Point2f` elements;

Try something like this instead:

```
    cv::Mat pointmatrix1(2, keypoints_matched_1.size(), CV_32F);
    int column = 0;
    for (auto& kp: keypoints_matched_1) {
        pointmatrix1.at<float>(0,column) = kp.pt.x;
        pointmatrix1.at<float>(1,column) = kp.pt.y;
        column++;
    }
```

Comment: The Error Changed to:error: (-215:Assertion failed) d == 2 && (sizes[0] == 1 || sizes[1] == 1 || sizes[0]*sizes[1] == 0) in function 'create'

Comment: Check the [doc](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d0/dbd/group__triangulation.html). There are many conditions for your inputs. Is `keypoints_matched_1.size()` equal to `keypoints_matched_2.size()` and both strictly positive? Also, shouldn't `points3D` be a single cv::Mat which the triangulatePoints() will resize to 3xN?

Comment: Thank you very much!
I changed the:
``std::vector<cv::Mat> points3D; `` to 
``cv::Mat points3D(3,keypoints_matched_1.size() ,CV_32F); ``

And now it looks like its working